# Kubernetes external access to application in container

Tags: centos, iptables, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I'm using kubernates on my cluster on Digital Ocean.

I have application inside container in Pod. And i need to make external connection to this application. I need access to concrete instance (cause i have more than 10 Pod with this application).

So, my question is: how can i make external access to this application.

For example i have public IP 192.168.9.9

And have 2 pods with instances. First listen port 8990 and it's Pod IP is 10.0.0.1 and second listen port 8991 and it's Pod IP is 10.0.0.1.

So, i need to redirect traffic from 192.168.9.9:8990 to 10.0.0.1:8990 and 192.168.9.9:8991 to 10.0.0.1:8991.

Yes, i can do it by using iptables manually. But i want to do it automatically. When new Pod is up, i want to make record in iptables.

I can watch for services by using api:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1beta1/watch/services
```

And can get ip of pod here:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1beta1/pods
```

I found solution that do something similar to my needs [here](https://github.com/larsks/kiwi/). But it looks like poor architectural decision. Is it better way to redirect external traffic to pod automatically after new Pod is up?

Answer (score 6):

If your public ip is configured on an interface on one of your minions, then all you need to do is set the `publicIPs` value in your service description.  For example, if you define a service like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1beta1
id: test-web
port: 8888
selector:
  name: test-web
containerPort: 80
publicIPs:
  - 192.168.1.43
```

Then Kubernetes will create iptables rules like this:

```
-A KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER -d 192.168.1.43/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment test-web -m tcp --dport 8888 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 38541
-A KUBE-PORTALS-HOST -d 192.168.1.43/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment test-web -m tcp --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.20:38541
```

These rules redirect traffic to your `publicIP` and port to the appropriate port maintained by the local `kube-proxy` instance.  I only wrote [kiwi](https://github.com/larsks/kiwi/) (and I'm sorry you don't like it!) to provide a mechanism for dynamically allocating public ip addresses.  As long as you don't mind pre-configuring the addresses on your interfaces, you should be all set.